# Can I add any column after I created My database?

Tags: django, django-models

I created my database using `python manage.py syncdb` And I tried to add another attribute to my model called `created_date` My site gives error.  And I deleted my db.sqlite3 file Then reorganize my model Then error went. I want to know is this correct

Comment: You should read about [migrations in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/) (note that this is a new feature in Django 1.7).

Comment: Wow thanks man. That is what I am looking for. I have not read django 1.7 doc until yet.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/) are the way to do this. Native migrations were only introduced in Django 1.7 but, since you're using `syncdb`, I'm guessing you're using an earlier version.

For earlier versions of Django you need a third-party app called [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) to handle migrations for you. This will then let you change your database after creation fairly painlessly in most cases.

Comment: yes I am using 1.6. For now I dont need any migration. But I wanted to know